# Meteor: helper variable not refreshing

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

In a meteor messenger app I have pages for each user you're talking to. But when you switch users it doesn't always switch the conversations.

It seems that the helper variable isn't refreshing. Any ideas?

```
Router.route('/cc/:name',{ 
      template: "cc",
      name: "cc",
      data: function(){
        var x = //...
        chat = Chats.find({users: {$all: [x, Meteor.userId()]}});
      }
    });
```

helper

```
Template.cc.helpers({
    'chat': function(){
        return chat
    }
});
```

template

```
<template name="cc">
 {{#each chat}}
    {{#each message}}
        <span>{{senderName}}</span>
        <b>{{content}}</b>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
 {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not reactive, becouse assigning is not an reactive operation. Helpers have *reactive context*, `Chats.find` is an *reactive data source*, but you have to read from *reactive data source* **in** *reactive context* to make it reactive.

**Solution A**:

It looks like an IronRouter, so pass data directly from Router. Read more [here](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data).

**Solution B**:

Turn `chat` into `ReactiveVar`. Read more [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg).